# MacOS High Sierra: disable tabs for all apps?

Tags: macos, high-sierra, preview, tabs

I want to turn off tabs for Preview especially. [Following these instructions](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25244?locale=en_US), I went to Dock and set “Prefer tabs when opening documents” to *Manually* - yet PDF documents keep opening up in new tabs in Preview when I open files I download from Chrome, open files from the terminal, or even if I click on them from the Finder. Help?

Answer (score 2):

Manually didn't work for me either. Only after I choose "In Full Screen Only", then toggled back to "Manually" did it do so.

Also, make sure in  System Preferences > General you don't have "Close windows when quitting an app" checked, as this may result in previously tabbed PDF's opening together.